# Weird behavior of selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

In the Shiny App below, I am facing a very strange behavior, where `selectInput` box slides downwards when I type something in this box. Also, the text inside `selectInput` box moves towards the right while I type in this box. I have spent a lot of time to find out the reason for this problem but could not figure it out. Can someone point out the mistake I am doing causing this strange behavior?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(highcharter)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "select_by", label = "Select by:", choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE, options = NULL)
  )   
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(
      side = "right",
      selected = "Tab1",
      tabPanel("Tab1", "Tab content 1", highchartOutput("tabset1Selected"))
    )
  ),
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    siderbar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    selectedVal <- reactiveValues()
    
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "select_by", choices = c(as.character(1:10000)), selected = 2, server = TRUE)
    
    output$tabset1Selected <- renderHighchart({
      selectedVal <- input$select_by
      print(highcharts_demo())
    })
    
  }
)
```

[image: selectInput moves when HighCharter used]

[image]

Comment: You could try setting the `width` and `size` arguments of `selectizeInput`. With 30k items, (re)fitting the updated dropdown might not go seamless. Not sure if it works though.

Comment: Checked, width and size are not the problems.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. My packages are all up to date. However, the difference is that I removed the highcharter package (wanted to try, first, without installing a new package). Can you confirm that?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem either. However, I did get some "blinking" of the select box about whenever I was typing in a new number. This went away when I set `server = FALSE`. Would this work for you as well?

Comment: @Jan: This problem happens only when ```highcharter``` package is used for rendering, removing this package will not produce this issue.

Comment: @jpiversen: I have set ```server = FALSE``` and the blinking went away but it defeated the purpose of loading ```choices``` dynamically (as the user types) in ```selectInput``` box as the number of choices is large and the loading time increased considerably. Also, I got the warning - ```Warning: The select input contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were on the right track. It has something to do with selectize.js updating the items from the server. You can verify that by setting the `loadThrottle` option to 5000. This option determines how long the widget waits "before requesting options from the server" (see [the manual](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)). Now you have to wait exactly 5 seconds and then the select widget flickers.

The issue seems to be caused by a CSS conflict. selectize.js adds a CSS class to the widget. If you remove that feature, the flicker goes away.

```
selectizeInput(inputId = "select_by", label = "Select by:", 
               choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE, 
               options = list(loadThrottle=200, loadingClass=""))
```

- `loadingClass` sets a specific CSS class (default: 'loading') while loading data from the server. Purpose: to change how the widget looks and communicate to users that an update is in progress.
- `loadThrottle` does not need to be set. It's default is 300. You can set it to any value that suits your needs.

**Details**

`highcharter` defines it's own CSS class names `loading` with these specs:

```
.loading {
  margin-top: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
}
```

That is the reason for the CSS conflict. The widget gets a top margin and it's content moved to the center, because the browser does not distinguish the source of the class. It only sees some CSS that fits and uses it. This image shows where you need to look:

[image: Developer tools reveal the problem]

Comment: Thanks, @Jan! You have nailed the issue and making the changes to ```loadingClass``` has removed the flickering. I have used Developer Tools in Chrome to see what CSS is loaded while focusing on ```selectInput``` but I could not see ```CSS class (default: 'loading')```. Are you using a different tool for debugging or I am looking at the wrong place? Apologies for such a noob question, I am new to debugging web applications.

Comment: Your debugging tool is fine. Selectize.js adds a class named "loading" to one of the `div`s that the select widget is composed of. It's hard to find because it gets added and removed again very fast. The default name of this class is set through Selectize.js, see [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#general).

Comment: Thanks, @Jan. I could not see the class ```loading``` (please see the screenshot in the question) and I suspect that is because of the errors I am getting - ```DevTools failed to load source map, could not load content for highchart.js.map```. To fix this issue I have modified the code as ```body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js")) ... ```,but still, ```highchart.js``` is not loaded correctly. Are you explicitly loading the ```highcharts.js``` file? Apologies for another silly question.

Comment: All you need to do is in the answer. Once you have fixed it, `loading` will **not** be added anymore. It only appears without the solution. And even then it only appears for a few milliseconds and then vanish again. It's easy to miss.

Comment: I can see it now, it shows up for a very brief period. Thanks, @Jan.